# gatsby-image-plugin, Absolute path in <StaticImage> component for static images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'd like to use an absolute path in the `src` prop of the `StaticImage` component in [gatsby-plugin-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#staticimage).

However, [the documentation says](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#staticimage) that `src` only accepts relative paths.

Given this directory structure:

```
├─ images/
│  ├─ image.png
├─ pages/
│  ├─ index.js
```

I currently have to do something like this:

```js
const IndexPage = () => (
  <div>
    <StaticImage src="../images/image.png" alt="image" />
  </div>
);
```

How can I get this instead?

```js
const IndexPage = () => (
  <div>
    <StaticImage src="src/images/image.png" alt="image" />
  </div>
);
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
const IndexPage = () => (
  <div>
    <StaticImage src="./src/images/image.png" alt="image" />
  </div>
);
```

Or:

```
const IndexPage = () => (
  <div>
    <StaticImage src="../../images/image.png" alt="image" />
  </div>
);
```

Both should work either way. The only problem you may be facing is the relativity of your paths. You may need to use `../..` (check it in your specific use-case) or use `./src/...`.